# Python handling NoneType when parsing tables

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, python-itertools, nonetype

I am trying to compare two tables (`table_a` and `table_b`) and subtract the last column of `table_a` from the last column of `table_b`. However, table_a includes an extra row and is causing me to get a `NoneType` Error. Is there a away I can still include the "Plums" row from `table_a` and just output `NULL` for the delta cell? Below is my testable code.

Current Code:

```
from datetime import datetime
import itertools

table_a = (
      (datetime(2016, 9, 28, 0, 0), 'Apples', 650, 700, 850),
      (datetime(2016, 9, 28, 0, 0), 'Oranges', 900, 950, 1000),
      (datetime(2016, 9, 28, 0, 0), 'Grapes', 1050, 1100, 1150),
      (datetime(2016, 9, 28, 0, 0), 'Plums', 2000, 3000, 4000)
      )

table_b = (
      (datetime(2016, 9, 27, 0, 0), 'Apples', 50, 150, 200),
      (datetime(2016, 9, 27, 0, 0), 'Oranges', 250, 350, 400),
      (datetime(2016, 9, 27, 0, 0), 'Grapes', 450, 550, 600),
      )

table_format = '{:<10}|{:<8}|{:<8}|{:<8}|{:<8}|{:<12}'
line_sep = ('-' * 60)

print(line_sep)
print(table_format.format('Date', 'Count_1', 'Count_2', 'Count_3' , 'Count_4', 'Count_4_Delta'))


for a, b in itertools.zip_longest(table_a, table_b):
      l = str(a[0])[0:10]
      m = a[1]
      n = a[2]
      o = a[3]
      p = a[4]
      q = b[4]
      print(line_sep)
      print(table_format.format(l, m, n, o, p, (p-q)))
```

Output with Error:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Date      |Count_1 |Count_2 |Count_3 |Count_4 |Count_4_Delta
------------------------------------------------------------
2016-09-28|Apples  |650     |700     |850     |650         
------------------------------------------------------------
2016-09-28|Oranges |900     |950     |1000    |600         
------------------------------------------------------------
2016-09-28|Grapes  |1050    |1100    |1150    |550         
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/test.py", line 30, in <module>
    q = b[4]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

If I add a if statement to remove NoneType it prints the table without an error but excludes the "Plums" row.

```
for a, b in itertools.zip_longest(table_a, table_b):
      if a and b is not None:
            l = str(a[0])[0:10]
            m = a[1]
            n = a[2]
            o = a[3]
            p = a[4]
            q = b[4]
            print(line_sep)
            print(table_format.format(l, m, n, o, p, (p-q)))
```

Output with If Statement:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Date      |Count_1 |Count_2 |Count_3 |Count_4 |Count_4_Delta
------------------------------------------------------------
2016-09-28|Apples  |650     |700     |850     |650         
------------------------------------------------------------
2016-09-28|Oranges |900     |950     |1000    |600         
------------------------------------------------------------
2016-09-28|Grapes  |1050    |1100    |1150    |550
```

I would like to have the below output. Where the "Plums" row still prints but has the string 'NULL" for the delta cell.

Desired Output:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Date      |Count_1 |Count_2 |Count_3 |Count_4 |Count_4_Delta
------------------------------------------------------------
2016-09-28|Apples  |650     |700     |850     |650         
------------------------------------------------------------
2016-09-28|Oranges |900     |950     |1000    |600         
------------------------------------------------------------
2016-09-28|Grapes  |1050    |1100    |1150    |550          
------------------------------------------------------------
2016-09-27|Plums   |2000    |3000    |4000    |NULL
```

Comment: This is the perfect application for the [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/) package. Check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) accepts an optional `fillvalue` parameter. If it's provided, it is used instead of `None`:

```
>>> list(itertools.zip_longest([1, 2, 3], [4, 5]))
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, None)]
>>> list(itertools.zip_longest([1, 2, 3], [4, 5], fillvalue='NULL'))
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 'NULL')]
```

You can provide empty row (a list of NULL values) as the `fillvalue`:

```
class EmptyValue:
    def __sub__(self, other):
        return 'NULL'
    def __rsub__(self, other):
        return 'NULL'

empty_row = [None, 'NULL', EmptyValue(), EmptyValue(), EmptyValue()]
for a, b in itertools.zip_longest(table_a, table_b, fillvalue=empty_row):
    ...
```

Comment: First thanks for looking. That snippet did resolve the NoneType error but the table is still not printing. Now I get error 'TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'str''.

Comment: @MBasith, You may need to use another value instead of `'NULL'` that can be used in `-` operation. I will update the answer.

Comment: Okay yes, I see. Cannot subtract and integer with a string.

Comment: This worked great. I'm not very familiar with classes yet but looks like they are quite valuable. If you have a moment can you please let me know what this class is doing?  Thank you so much for your help. Well appreciated.

Comment: @MBasith, The special method `__sub__` is used when you subtract value from `EmptyValue` instance. `__rsub__` is used when you subtract `EmptyValue` instance from other value.  In other word, `EmptyValue() - 1` calls `EmptyValue().__sub__(1)`; `1 - EmptyValue()` calls `EmptyValue().__rsub__(1)` (operator overloading). I hope my explanation makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

[zip_longest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) returns a singular `None` type when it runs out of values. You want a list of `None`s or you get a `TypeError` when you try and use the subscript `[]` operator.

Use the optional fillvalue to get a list of `None`s and then test for `None` when you format for output so you don't get another `TypeError` when you try and do `p-q` when `q` is `None`:

```
for a, b in itertools.zip_longest(table_a, table_b,fillvalue=[None]*5):
    l = str(a[0])[0:10]
    m = a[1]
    n = a[2]
    o = a[3]
    p = a[4]
    q = b[4]
    print(line_sep)
    print(table_format.format(l, m, n, o, p, (p-q) if q is not None else 'NULL'))
```

Comment: @dawg This solution is short and sweet. Worked great. Thank you!